# Flex, выровнять ссылки в шапке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать ссылки по горизонтали 
собственно когда добавляю флекс получается вот 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.top-nav_menu {
  display: flex;
}
.top-nav_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.top-nav_menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav_menu">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-md">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md -->
    <div class="col-md">
      <img src="img/NewProvidence@1X.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md -->
    <div class="col-md">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>

        <li>
          <button class="btn-app">Get App</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Не могу разобраться.

Comment: добавил html код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `display: flex;` спискам (`ul`):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-nav_menu>.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: crimson;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

.top-nav_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-nav_menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav_menu">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="col-md">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md -->
    <div class="col-md">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md -->
    <div class="col-md">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn-app">Get App</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
```